# Weird characters showing up when importing from csv files in sql

Tags: sql, csv, psql

I'm trying to import data from a csv file into SQL but I keep getting the error

```
\copy owner (owner_id, owner_name, owner_surname) FROM 'C:\Users\Documents\owners.csv' DELIMITER ',';
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "ï»¿0"
CONTEXT:  COPY owner, line 1, column owner_id: "ï»¿0"
```

Here's what owners.csv looks like

[image]

I understand that the error is to do with the encoding and that I should change the encoding to UTF 8 BOM, which I have done but the error still persist

Answer (score 0):

`ï»¿0` in WIN1252 is hexadecimal 0xEFBBBF30, which would be a BOM and a 0.

Remove that BOM from the file, and you will get better results.